# video play in UIView in ios

Tags: ios

I  am developing an app in objective-c.

In my UIViewController

.h file

```
@property(weak,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIView *vvv;
```

.m file

```
  // to play the video
    NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"alphabet learning splash" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];


    self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];
    self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
    AVPlayerLayer *videoLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];

    [_vvv.layer addSublayer:videoLayer];
    [self.view addSubview:_vvv];
    [ self.avPlayer play];
```

But the video is not displaying in the  UIView of vvv.How to set?

Comment: Have you tried setting the frames/bounds of the video view?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the bounds

```
// to play the video
NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"alphabet learning splash" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];


self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];
self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
AVPlayerLayer *videoLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];

[_vvv.layer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[self.view addSubview:_vvv];
_vvv.frame = self.bounds;
[ self.avPlayer play];
```

Comment: i need to repeat the video until the uiviewcontroller goes to next screen.how to do

Comment: try: self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.play

Comment: showing error as ;-not used avplayeractionatitemend

Comment: i have a douth after display the video i have used popupimage in other uiview .at that time i need to make video stop and video background should appear little dark how to do